# How to autorun functions on JavaScript/HTML

Tags: html

```js
function myFunction() {
    alert("Lol");
    }
```

```html
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
```

That's my code and I am wanting this to run automatically when opened up. It should run the function and a pop up box will open in 0.5 seconds. When the pop up box is closed, another one is opened in 0.5 seconds.Just to clarify, this is mainly used for pranking my friend and I had the working code but my system crashed and the file got corrupted/other, either way it no longer works and I can't seem to remember the code exactly. Please can someone help me get this code up and working again. I only want it to open a pop up box and nothing else as I know this could be used as a method to spam others however this will be used fro nothing but me and my friends work. Thank you again.P.S. I have had to add a space between my  and my  as other wise it would not let me post this question.

Comment: Simply put `setTimeout(myFunction, 500);` after your `alert`, but most modern browsers have anti spam to suppress spam like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to launch the code when a page with this script load :

```
window.onload = function() {
    setInterval('alert("Lol")', 500); //Actualisation 0.5s
};
```

Or this to use the button :

```
function myFunction() {
    setInterval('alert("Lol")', 500);
}
```

If u want to stop this interval, not useful here but good to know

```
var intervalID = setInterval('alert("Lol")', 500);

//Later in the process
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

Comment: don't forget to clear the interval, if you want to stop the function call

Comment: Thank you everyone for helping me with this

Comment: sorry Im new to this.

Answer (score 0):

eventlisteners usually work:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //show popup
});
```